# Streaming rgb images together with depth information

Tags: video-streaming

I have learned that it's possible to stream 3-channel images over networks with protocols like rtsp or http.

Now, given rgb images and depth images obtained from 3D camera (such as [intel realsense](https://click.intel.com/intelr-realsensetm-depth-camera-d435.html)), is there a standard way to stream these images synchronously over networks? Do I need to create 2 streams simultaneously, one for rgb and the other for depth?

Are there any libraries out there doing this? (python preferred)

Thanks in advance